# Disable from component to rerender when coming from redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a *login* component that uses redux as state management.
Every time the component rendered, I am resetting the state to the initial.
I have an issue once I am redirecting to this login page with some *statusCode*, I would like to display this error message inside the *login* component and not reset the state.
How can I avoid from component to rerender once it arrives from a redirect (routing)?
I am using middleware for defining the *statusCode* and act accordingly -> 
for example:

Middleware:

```
  if (action.type === SUCCESS_LOGOUT) {
    console.log("we are here - Middleware -> SUCCESS_LOGOUT");
    clearAuthorization();
    resetClient();
    dispatch(licenseExpired(action.statusCode));
  }
```

Actions:

```
const licenseExpired = statusCode => async dispatch => {
  console.log("we are in actions License");
  console.log("TOTO " + statusCode);
  try {
     dispatch(errorReset(statusCode));
  } catch (e) {
     dispatch(failedLogout(e));
  }
};
```

Reducer:

```
 [ERROR_RESET]: (state, { statusCode }) => {
   return {
     ...state,
     statusCode: statusCode === 402 ? statusCode : '',
  };
 }
```

Redirect:

```
const shouldRedirect = WrappedComponent => props => {
const { redirect, url } = props;
 return redirect ? <Redirect to={url} /> : <WrappedComponent 
 {...props} 
 />;
};
```

Component - custom hook:

```
const Login = ({ onLogin, isLoading, statusCode, errorReset }) => {
const errorResetMessage = useCallback(() => errorReset(),
  [statusCode]);

useEffect(() => {
return () => errorResetMessage();
}, [errorResetMessage]);
```

Comment: Any code about your `<Route />` and `<Redirect />`?

Comment: @keikai - edited in the original message.

Comment: I don't think you need `disable the rerender`. First, redirect calls rendering your component, you need to render something or it would stop in the prev page. Second, if you make your `target page` input text **controlled** (for example: bind with redux state), you won't lost it while rendering. You only lost the state during `re-rendering`

Comment: Is there a way to control it over the my hook inside the component? for example: if it comes from redirecting the component shouldn't be rendered ? or if the page is refreshed, the component should be rendered ?

Comment: There always have a way to do it. But since you haven't shown the related code, I can't help anymore. Maybe you could make your code an online demo which would help a lot.

Comment: my current hook is:                                                                                                    
  const Login = ({ onLogin, isLoading, statusCode, errorReset }) => {
  const errorResetMessage = useCallback(() => errorReset(),
      [statusCode]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => errorResetMessage();
  }, [errorResetMessage]);

Comment: Update it in your question